Where should I ask this question?
I have read the tour and understand from it that I will not be able to ask the question I joined the site for...
I want to describe behaviour that an individual is exhibiting in the hopes of determining if they do have psychological problems that need to be addressed.
The individual admits that they have a problem but does seek help and does not admit the behaviour that causes family problems to be part of their problem.
Does anyone know where (not just SE websites) I could ask a question of such a nature in the hopes of getting some perspective for myself? I am in a small town and the nearest psychologists are about 3 hours drive from here.

The only place on the SE network that might conceivably take the question would be [interpersonal.se]. The likely upshot after any advice may well be "go talk to a doctor" I would suspect. Priests, family friends etc..

SE is really not designed for self-help, I doubt any site will take it.

I should have clarified that part of the question by stating that I am not hoping to find such a place on any of the SE sites - thus far they seem to be useless for many of the common  practical questions in life that also revolve around a respective topic.

Psychological problems are just as much about health as heart problems, tumors, bone fractures.
When you have those sorts of issues, you need the help of a medical professional to diagnose. There isn't a substitute online forum. Sure, there are sites that try or claim to provide this, but I think it's important to recognize that it's against medical professional ethics to provide diagnoses without examining the patient. That means that anyone who provides such diagnostic information is either A) Behaving unethically, against the norms and guidelines of their field, or B) Not really part of the field they claim to be and therefore not a professional.
